# In DCL Singleton without volatile, can NULL check be optimised out?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, singleton

A simple DCL singleton:

```
class Singleton {
 public:
  Singleton* GetInstance();

 private:
  Singleton() = default;

  static Singleton* s_instance;
  static std::mutex s_mutex;
};

Singleton* Singleton::GetInstance() {
  if (s_instance == nullptr) { // 1st check
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mutex);
    if (s_instance == nullptr) { // 2nd (double) check
      s_instance = new Singleton();
    }
  }
  return s_instance;
}
```

Here is my question:
Papers like [this](https://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) talk extensively about compiler optimisations can cause memory/ instruction reordering causing any of the thread to crash.

But I didn't find any article talking about NULL check might getting optimised out if `s_instance` is not volatile. **As no article talks about it, I need someone to verify if that's even possible.**

I mean compiler converting the code to something like this:

```
class Singleton {
 public:
  Singleton* GetInstance();

 private:
  Singleton() = default;

  static Singleton* s_instance;
  static std::mutex s_mutex;
};

Singleton* Singleton::GetInstance() {
  if (s_instance == nullptr) { // 1st check
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mutex);
    **// 2nd (double) check optimized out**
    s_instance = new Singleton();
  }
  return s_instance;
}
```

Comment: Is this C++11 or above? If so, why not just us a function-scoped static variable? It gets initialized on first-entry, and is thread-safe

Comment: I know that, the question here is can optimiser optimise out one of the NULL checks?

Comment: You have a data race on `s_instance` which is UB, so theoretically all bets are off anyway (regardless of what the compiler optimizes). You need to make `s_instance` atomic!

Answer (score 1):

What optimizations a compiler may perform vary from compiler-to-compiler, and based on optimization flags; there is no "one true answer", so you must always verify independently for your own code. Different compilers have different optimizations, and certain flags or intrinsics will change the way an optimizer views assembly.

As long as the code being checked does not have any undefined behavior, the best way to determine if something gets optimized out is to check the assembly. If the code sample is small enough, a simple tool you can use is [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org).

Testing your example using gcc-10.2 and `-O3` reveals that **no checks get optimized out**.

For the double-checked code, we see the assembly contain:

```
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR Singleton::s_instance[rip]
        test    rax, rax                                  ; This is for the first test
        je      .L25                                      ; branch on the results
        ret
.L25:
        ...
        call    __gthrw_pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t*) ; acquire lock
        ...
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR Singleton::s_instance[rip]
        test    rax, rax                                  ; The second test
        je      .L6                                       ; branch on the results
```

So during initialization, both checks will occur -- whereas the first check will occur every time `GetInstance()` is entered.

I believe the second check **cannot be optimized out** here for two reasons:

1. The C++ language must assume that `__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lock` may access and alias `s_instance`, which means that the compiler must assume that it may be modified. This would force a new lookup from main memory, which also necessitates the new check.
2. The compiler may be aware that `__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lock` causes a synchronization point, which will change this thread's view of the data. Synchronization points also force reloads of data from main memory rather than relying on processor caches. This, similarly, would necessitate the new check and no assumptions to be made

As was pointed out in the comments by mpoeter, it's worth noting that the non-atomic comparison against `m_instance` is actually **undefined behavior** if this is in a threaded context. Analyzing the generated assembly from a program with undefined behavior is a pointless exercise, since the compiler is given free reign of what it generates (if it generates assembly for UB at all).

---

Since you're just trying to create a thread-safe initialization of a singleton, you can actually just do this safely with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) function-scoped static variables, which are *guaranteed* to be thread-safe for initialization.

Your code can be rewritten simply as:

```cpp
class Singleton {
public:
  Singleton* GetInstance();

private:
  Singleton() = default;

};

Singleton* Singleton::GetInstance() {
  // Initialized exactly once, in a thread-safe way
  static auto s_instance = new Singleton();

  return s_instance;
}
```

[See the assembly comparison here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4x679M)

It's worth noting that function-scoped static variables are also initialized by a double-check pattern as well, but produce assembly that uses intrinsics rather than explicit syscalls. If you check the link above, you will see this initialization become:

```
Singleton::GetInstance():
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR ; guard variable for Singleton::GetInstance()::s_instance[rip]
        test    al, al        ; first test for initialization
        je      .L16
        ...
.L16:
        push    rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT     ; guard variable for Singleton::GetInstance()::s_instance
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire  ; acquire exclusive lock
        test    eax, eax             ; second test, after locking segment
        jne     .L17
        ...
```

---

In either case, the second check *existing* in the assembly does not mean that it will be triggered on each invocation. Since initialization only occurs on first entry, this branch will very seldomly be taken.

Comment: Why compiler does not optimize on e of the NULL checks?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it's likely because `s_instance` is a mutable static variable -- so the compiler _has_ to assume that there may be some other object interacting with it that might change it's state. C++ allows for ways to break `private` access via friendship or templates, which means the compiler can't assume that just because `s_instance` is private, it won't be modified by anyone else back to `nullptr`

Comment: ok, but there are 2 consecutive  NULL checks for the same variable, compiler should be able to optimize it out unless the variable is declared volatile, isn't it?

Comment: A quick test shows that [hiding the scope of `s_instance` using double-checking](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Whdjn7) creates assembly nearly identical to the function-level `static` code -- so I think my guess about visibility of `s_instance` is likely related. If you throw `s_instance` in an unnamed namespace, it generates considerably better assembly

Comment: @user2407394 You might find better assembly gets generated with other compilers in the same circumstances; the example I gave was just with GCC by doing a simple examination of the generated assembly. I can't answer why the double-check isn't specifically optimized out here; I can only guess. It could be that the mutex causes a synchronization point which forces a new check. Results will vary based on compiler, flags, input, etc.

Comment: Thanks, That sounds like a plausible point, I'll wait for a more confirmed answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain some more information. It is unlikely that the second guard can be optimized out due to the compiler having to assume that aliasing may occur, and possibly due to the introduction of a synchronization point from locking. However this second check should not negatively affect performance, since only the first check will ever be done on subsequent accesses.